# value is not updated in python using self.counter

Tags: python-3.x

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02cgg.png)

Above code displays output as 10 10 but i used change_counter to update counter value to 11. why is it not updating
Can someone help me plz

Comment: `obj.change_counter` should be `obj.change_counter()`, and it should be `obj.counter`, not `demo.counter`

Comment: Please include code as text rather than as image. [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you are accessing a static variable.
When you write:

```
print(demo.counter)
```

it will always print the number 10, because it is defined this way in the demo-class.

If you want the value to be changed after calling obs.change_counter() you need to access the value of the object "obj" not the class demo.

Another mistake you have made is that you never actually call obj.change_counter, because you forgot the brackets for the function call. The statement obj.change_counter does not throw an error in python but it also wont have any effect.

So instead of this:

```
obj = demo()
print(demo.counter)
obj.change_counter
print(demo.counter)
```

You have to do this:

```
obj = demo()
print(obj.counter)    # <- notice the reference to the object
obj.change_counter()  # <- notice the brackets
print(obj.counter)
```